# Apache Spark JavaRDD group by 2 fields and get sum of third field for a custom type object

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am using Java 8 for my spark job.

I have below class that I need to process:

```
public class MyModel implements Serializable {

  private String region;

  private String keyword;

  private Long termFrequency;

}
```

I have applied below processing:

```
JavaRDD<MyModel> processedRows =
        csvLines
            .filter(myFilterObj)
            .map(myMapObj);
```

Which gives me below result:

```
region   |   keyword   | termFrequency
--------------------------------
REGION1  |   milk      | 200
REGION2  |  lemon      | 100
REGION1  |  milk       | 100
```

I want to group my records by `region` and `keyword` and add the `termFrequency` and want the output result as below:

```
    region   |   keyword   | termFrequency
    --------------------------------
    REGION1  |   milk      | 300
    REGION2  |  lemon      | 100
```

How can I achieve this in JavaRDD?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, if the best approach but you can convert to JavaPairRDD using a Tuple2 of region and keyboard as a key and MyModel as a value.

Then you call reduceByKey with a function to sum the termFrequency.

Finally, if you need you can map to any given JavaRDD (JavaRDD for example)

```
            .mapToPair(myModel -> new Tuple2<>(new Tuple2<>(myModel.getRegion(), myModel.getKeyword()), myModel.getTermFrequency))
            .reduceByKey((v1, v2) -> v1 + v2)
            .map(v1 -> new MyModel(v1._1._1, v1._1._2, v1._2))
```

You could also use a helper class instead of Tuple just to make the code more readable